# Laravel and Geocoding markers (nearby users) do not update correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, laravel-5

I try to show on a google map markers that are near the current positon. If the map is dragged it will update the center coordinates and recalculate the markers around that center. The initial markers around the current users positon are showing correctly but when i drag the map they stay all the time the same. The update and the POST both is happening (my guess that the POST is not finished before the markers reload, so the old ones stay). The sourrounding markers are stored in a session variable.

Controller showNearbyUsers method:

```
/**
 * Shows the users near the current one
 *
 * @return void
 */
public static function showNearbyUsers($centerlat,$centerlng)
{
    try {
        // Delete the session variable
        if (Session::has('nearbies'))
        {
            Session::forget('nearbies');
        }

        // Define max, min for lat and lng
        $centerlatlow = $centerlat-0.25;
        $centerlathigh = $centerlat+0.25;
        $centerlnglow = $centerlng-0.25;
        $centerlnghigh = $centerlng+0.25;

        $nearbies = DB::table('positions')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'positions.users_id')
                                          ->where('users_id', '!=', Auth::id())
                                          ->whereBetween('lat', array($centerlatlow, $centerlathigh))
                                          ->whereBetween('lng', array($centerlnglow, $centerlnghigh))
                                          ->select('positions.*', 'users.name', 'users.level')
                                          ->get();

        if ($nearbies) {
            return Session::put('nearbies', $nearbies);
        }
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        Session::flash('message', 'An error occured with your localization. Enable GPS and refresh.');
        Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger');
    }
}
```

View Script

```
<script>
// Auto adjust map div
$(window).resize(function () {
    var h = $(window).height(),
    offsetTop = 220; // Calculate the top offset
    $('#map_canvas').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
}).resize();

// Setup token security
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
});

// Attributes
var map;
var geocoder;
var markers = Array();      // Contains x,y
var users = Array();        // Contains whole user info
var current = Array();
var infoWindows = Array();
var mapCenter;

// Test initialize users array
//users = [['Brugg',47.47963,8.18465],['Aarau',47.39340,8.04312],['Baden',47.47377,8.30647]];

// Initialize the map with logged in user
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    getLocation();
}

// Set nearby user markers
function setMarkers(list) {
    for(var i=0; i<list[0].length; i++){
        var element = (list[0])[i];
        var nearbyLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(element['lat'], element['lng']);
        console.log((list[0])[i]);
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: nearbyLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: element['name'],
            infoWindowIndex : i
        });

        infoWindows[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content : element['name']
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click',
            function(event)
            {
                infoWindows[this.infoWindowIndex].open(map, this);
            }
        );
    }
}

// Delete nearby user markers
function deleteMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}

// Map dragging listener. Updates the nearby users markers
function mapDragListener() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
        deleteMarkers();
        mapCenter = map.getCenter();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "updatenearbies/"+mapCenter.lat()+"/"+mapCenter.lng(),
            async: false
        });
        @if(Session::has('nearbies'))
            <?php $test = Session::get('nearbies'); ?>
            users = [<?php echo json_encode($test); ?>];
            console.log(users);
        @endif
        setMarkers(users);
    });
}

// Map zoom listener. Updates the nearby users markers
function mapZoomListener() {

}

// Get current user location
function getLocation() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

// If success in finding current position
function geoSuccess(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    // Send to geocoordinates.php and save to DB
    $.post("updateme/"+lat+"/"+lng);
    mainMapCalc(lat, lng);
}

// If no success in finding current position
function geoError() {
    alert("Please enable Geo-Location and Refresh the Website.");
}

// Set the logged in users and build up the environment
function mainMapCalc(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if(results[1]) {
                //formatted address
                var address = results[0].formatted_address;
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 18,
                        center: results[0].geometry.location,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                    mapCenter = map.getCenter();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "updatenearbies/"+mapCenter.lat()+"/"+mapCenter.lng(),
                        async: false
                    });
                    <?php $test = Session::get('nearbies'); ?>
                    users = [<?php echo json_encode($test); ?>];
                    setMarkers(users);      // Set initial nearby markers
                    mapDragListener();      // Register Listener
                    //mapZoomListener();      // TODO: Register Listener
                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Geocoder Error// No results found");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocoder Error// Failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}

// Show Map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Where is here the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are sending out the ajax request, but you are not doing anything with the returned data. Try changing

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updatenearbies/"+mapCenter.lat()+"/"+mapCenter.lng(),
    async: false
});
```

to

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updatenearbies/"+mapCenter.lat()+"/"+mapCenter.lng(),
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // request succeeded
        // data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // the request failed
    }
});
```

Also note that `async: false` is deprecated: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options, so you should use callbacks as shown above.